# How can I remove a GitHub pull request for version branches

Tags: github

I keep released major versions as distinct remote branches for further bug fixes (e.g. branch 0.1, 0.2 from which bug fix releases are tagged). For some reason – and I think this is because of the new interface – GitHub suggest to do a review of this branch and issue a pull request.

[image: Wrong pull request]

Of course, this is not what I have in mind with these kind of branches. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: You could create a tag, and create a branch from this tag only when you actually need to create a bug fix (which will be merged into master to also fix the bug in the main development branch). Or you could simply ignore this button.

Comment: But this would only help for single bug fixes. Usually I want to accumulate several (minor) bug fixes before releasing a new bug fix release. Of course in the mean time the fixes are also cherry-picked into master.

Comment: Why would it help only for single bug fixes? A branch is a branch. You're not forced to delete it as soon as you have implemented a bug fix.

Comment: Well, then I misunderstood your initial answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove it. Or you should just ignore it.

If you still want to mark milestones or release versions, consider using tags instead of branches.

If you use tags it also neatly folds into [GitHub's Releases feature](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software).